# Manipulate DOM and TS data

Tags: angular, dom, parent-child

I display a list of IDs, by searching for them in my database. In my ngfor loop I dragged a child component. Can I retrieve each ID in each childcomponent ?

i want get each value of  "GameToDisplay.key" in players.ts  in order to call each data by this key.
Tk you

```
<div *ngFor="let GameToDisplay  of GamesToDisplay | async">
{{GameToDisplay.key}}
<app-players></app-players>
</div>
```

Comment: `Players.ts` refers to `<app-players>` ?

Comment: yess it is ! i want retrieve dynamicly GameToDisplay.key tomake a call with this id in each <app-players. it is possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the data and access it on `players.ts`

```
<div *ngFor="let GameToDisplay  of GamesToDisplay | async">
{{GameToDisplay.key}}
<app-players [data]="GameToDisplay.key"></app-players> //data is not the fixed name
</div>
```

On your `players.ts`

```
@Input('data') key: any; // replace any by your key type;

 ngOnInit(){
 console.log(key);
}
```

Comment: My friend,
thanks to you i just had a very important click .... thank you very much